# React - Maximum update depth exceeded / Cannot update a component while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying out [useFormContext](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFormContext) in react to update a form by adding another section. Here's my code so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-swanson-fiomq

I have the following:

- `season_form.js` - the main form
- `season_data_form.js` - the sub-form; originally, this was the only one being called by `season_form`.
- `challenge_form.js` - this is the new section, also called by `season_form`.

My idea was to take out the form hooks from `season_data_form.js` and `challenge_form.js`, move it to `season_form.js`, and use `useFormContext` to transfer stuff in between, such as the registers, and submit actions.

However, I keep getting the following error, when run locally:

> Cannot update a component (`SeasonForm`) while rendering a different
> component (`SeasonDataForm`).

And then somewhere down the line, it says this:

> Maximum update depth exceeded

I'm not sure which one to take first.

Near as I can tell, it happens in `season_form.js`, whenever the user tries to load the data in `currentSeasonData` by changing the value of `seasonIndex`:

```
const SeasonForm = () => {
    const [seasonsData, setSeasonsData] = useState();
    const [seasonIndex, setSeasonIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentSeasonData, setCurrentSeasonData] = useState(null);

    const formMethods = useForm({ mode: "onBlur" });
    const { register, errors, control, handleSubmit, reset, formState, setError } = formMethods;

    const onSubmit = async (data) => { console.log(data); };

    useEffect((_) => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                let data_seasons = await dbGetSeasons();
                setSeasonsData(data_seasons);
                if (data_seasons[0]) { setSeasonIndex(data_seasons[0].id); }
                // ^^ Comment that out and the page will load, but will crash the moment you select anything in the dropdown.
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

    fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect((_) => {
        seasonsData &&
        seasonsData.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.id === seasonIndex) { setCurrentSeasonData(data); }
        });
    },
    [seasonIndex]
    );

    return (
    <Box>
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                {currentSeasonData ? (
                    <> {currentSeasonData.shortname} ({currentSeasonData.name}) </>
                ) : (
                    <>Choose a season...</>
                )}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>

            {seasonsData && (
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                {seasonsData.map((season) => {
                    const seasonKey = "season-" + season.id;
                    return (
                    <Dropdown.Item key={seasonKey} onClick={() => { setSeasonIndex(season.id); }}>
                        {season.shortname} ({season.name})
                    </Dropdown.Item> );
                })}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            )}
        </Dropdown>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="toggle_season">
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Card>
                <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="toggle_season">
                <Button variant="link">Season Data and Battle Pass</Button>
                </Accordion.Toggle>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="toggle_season">
                <Card.Body>
                    {currentSeasonData ? (<SeasonDataForm seasonData={currentSeasonData} />) : null}
                </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
            <Card>
                <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="toggle_challenges">
                <Button variant="link">Challenges</Button>
                </Accordion.Toggle>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="toggle_challenges">
                <Card.Body>
                    {currentSeasonData && currentSeasonData.pass_data && currentSeasonData.pass_data.challenges ? (
                        <ChallengeForm challenges={currentSeasonData.pass_data.challenges || {}} />
                    ) : (
                        <Alert variant="danger">Missing `challenges` data</Alert>
                    )}
                </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
        </Accordion>
    </Box> );
};

export default SeasonForm;
```

I really can't pinpoint what's happening. My limited experience with react tells me that some value somewhere, when changed, causes an infinite loop.

Of note is that commenting out `<SeasonDataForm>` allows the page to work, albeit with half the subforms gone.

Any ideas where I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following

```
const methods = useFormContext();
const register = methods.register();
const errors = methods.errors;
const control = methods.control;
const handleSubmit = methods.handleSubmit();
const reset = methods.reset;
const formState = methods.formState;
const setError = methods.setError();
const clearErrors = methods.clearErrors();
```

to

```
const methods = useFormContext();
const register = methods.register;
const errors = methods.errors;
const control = methods.control;
const handleSubmit = methods.handleSubmit;
const reset = methods.reset;
const formState = methods.formState;
const setError = methods.setError;
const clearErrors = methods.clearErrors;
```

It doesn't seem like the infinite loop is from your SeasonData, but because your are reassigning the functions to those variables, its not an issue to do so,
but the problem is that you are not just reassigning the functions to new variables, you are executing them by using "()", thats different you are getting the result of the function call not the function itself that way, so i removed the "()" from all except from "useFormContext()" where its mostly intentionally done ,

I hope this fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied over your code, but while it got rid of the `Cannot update a component while rendering a different component`, I'm still experiencing the `Maximum update depth exceeded` issue.

Of note is that the sandbox seems to be running with your code, but it's still broken here and there, and is not a complete copy of the code I run locally. I'll try to see if I can update it to be any more similar.